# Who are the characters in the Marvel Universe Wiki background?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I was browsing the Marvel Universe wiki and liked the cool background but do not know all the characters are. I can only name some of them: Spider-man, Captain America, Thor, Black Widow, Iron Man (model 42 armor), Hawkeye, Hulk, and Wolverine. This is the image from the site:

[image: Two pillars of Marvel heroes]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left side, top-to-bottom:

1. Captain America
2. Captain Universe
3. Spider-Man
4. Thor
5. Black Widow

Right side, top-to-bottom:

1. Iron Man
2. Hawkeye
3. Sunspot
4. Hulk
5. Wolverine

Captain Universe's inclusion provides the hint that the firey fellow isn't Human Torch.  The lines on the character's body match [his Avengers outfit](http://marvel.wikia.com/Roberto_da_Costa_%28Earth-616%29) as well.  These are Hickman's Avengers from his current run on the Avengers books.

Comment: You could be right about cannonball. Do you mean the Sam Guthrie character?

Comment: @neilfein Actually, that's an error, that's totally Sunspot, with his body dark, surrounded by fire.

Comment: I can't find any pictures of sunspot that look like that, but I can't find any pics of either of the human torches either. So I'm not sure. It would be weird if the Marvel Wiki front page had no members of the Fantastic Four in it, I'd think. Deleting my answer for now to avoid confusion, but I'll keep looking for backup.

Comment: @neilfein Google 'marvel sunspot avengers' to see his current costume.